# managed code calling unmanaged function

Tags: c++-cli

I have a struct declared in a managed code namespace in my c++-cli app. Included in  the project are also cpp files that are unmanaged. I try to call a function that is defined in the umanaged c++ code.  I pass it the struct from the managed world. The linker is complaining. It says

> Error 27  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl
>   N_MMOD(struct DoAT::CAD_CAC_params *)"
>   (?N_MMOD@@$$FYAHPEAUCAD_CAC_params@DoATR@@@Z) referenced in
>   function "public: int __clrcall DoAT::atrClass1::read_hdf5_file(class
>   System::String ^,class DoAT::HdfCallVars ^)"
>   (?read_hdf5_file@atrClass1@DoAT@@$$FQE$AAMHPE$AAVString@System@@PE$AAVHdfCallVars@2@@Z)   C:\DoAT\DoAT.obj    DoAT

How do I resolve this linking problem? I'm very new to the managed code world.
thanks,
sb

Comment: This is a rather horribly named function.  Hard to believe "N_MMOD" is a C++ function, even though it was parsed as one.  Sounds more like Fortran.  In which case the declaration of the function just is not correct.  Maybe `extern "C"` is missing.  Find the guy that wrote this code.  Whack him with the New York Times Sunday edition.

Comment: hahahaha, thank you Hans for the morning laugh!